# Rxjs throttleTime - update the throttling in realtime?

Tags: rxjs

Is there a way to update the throttleTime in Rxjs. You're scrolling near the bottom of the page, so we only need throttle every 400ms, while as you get nearer the top, we increate to 100ms as the target area is in that region

```
this.scrollSubscription$ = this.scrollSubject$
                .asObservable()
                .throttleTime(200, undefined, throttleTimeConfig)
                .subscribe(event => this.throttledScrollHandler(event));
```

What I am going to do is have two separate subscripbtions, as I cannot find a way of doing it.

```
this.slowerSubscriber$ = this.scrollSubject$
                    .asObservable()
                    .throttleTime(400,.......
```

Thought I would ask as I can't think of another way of achieving it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`throttle`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttle) to implement your own silencing duration:

```
// Make this function extract the position using scrollY, page offsets or whatever you want to use
const getScrollPositionFromEvent = event => 42;
this.scrollSubject$.asObservable()
  .throttle(event => Observable.interval(
    getScrollPositionFromEvent(event) <= 100 ? 100 : 400
  ))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

You can see a working example [here](https://rxviz.com/v/xOvAwvo2). It simply emits by a given input, which in your case would be based on the scroll offset.

Comment: It looks like the demo link doesn't work for me anymore – that's odd. So just to be clear, that 404 animation is not my demo. :-)

Comment: I've fixed the link, for what it's worth!

Comment: Ah, interesting. For whatever reason it 404s for me. I'll report an issue to rxviz. :-)

Comment: Yeah, the updated link now also 404s for me. Super weird. I've reported [this here](https://github.com/moroshko/rxviz/issues/12), perhaps it's just a temporary issue with the snippet database.